# How do I perform aggregation of messages(events) in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have the following attributes:

1. OrgId
2. DeviceId
3. ResponseId

I want to aggregate the number of devices for an organisation and no of responses for an organisation each time a response comes. I cannot think of an appropriate structure for aggregation.

Comment: Try using a KTable in Kafka Streams?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question. Leaving aside technology choice for a moment, If were to express an answer in pseudo-SQL it would look like this:

> I want to aggregate the number of devices for an organisation

```
SELECT OrgId,COUNT DISTINCT(DeviceId) FROM inbound_data GROUP BY OrgId
```

> Number of responses for an organisation each time a response comes

```
SELECT OrgId, COUNT DISTINCT(ResponseId) FROM inbound_data GROUP BY OrgId
```

So now it's just how to implement this. If you're already using Apache Kafka, then you have the Kafka Streams API to do it in Java, and you also have KSQL to do it in SQL. I'm not sure if `COUNT DISTINCT` is supported yet though.